# Proper nested align? Or split in align?

Tags: align, amsmath, split

Say I have a short line and a split long line, both of which I wish to left-justify, while also aligning the long line at the equals sign.
The following code...

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    &f(x)=x^2-x-1\\
    &g(x)=\frac{1}{2}-x\\
    \begin{split}
    (f\circ g)&=f(g(x))=f(\frac{1}{2}-x)=(\frac{1}{2}-x)^2-(\frac{1}{2}-x)-1\\
    &= \frac{1}{4}-x+x^2-\frac{1}{2}+x-1
    \end{split}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Gives the following result...

[image: result equation]

The third and fourth line are properly aligned, but they're not left-justified with the first and second, which is what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Put the `&` in front of the `=` in the first two lines, too.

Comment: @ABC I'm sorry, I must've been unclear — I want to left-justify all the lines while maintaining equals-alignment of the long line. As if it were in a notebook. I edited my post slightly

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your first question is great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to economize on (vertical) space, I suggest you use two nested `aligned` environments inside `\[ ... \]` rather than nest an `aligned` environment inside an `align*` environment. I would also argue that replacing all instances of `\frac` with `\tfrac` not only economizes on vertical space even more, it also helps establish more of a visual balance between the various quadratic, linear, and constant terms.

[image]

A final remark: I can't help but note that using nested `aligned` environments does not do all that much to enhance appearance. A single `aligned` environment, with all five rows aligned on the first `=` symbols per row, would work just as well -- if not even a bit better...

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'aligned' environment

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{aligned}
    &f(x)=x^2-x-1\\
    &g(x)=\tfrac{1}{2}-x\\
    &\begin{aligned}
    (f\circ g)(x) &=f(g(x))=f\bigl(\tfrac{1}{2}-x\bigr)=\bigl(\tfrac{1}{2}-x\bigr)^2-\bigl(\tfrac{1}{2}-x\bigr)-1\\
                  &= \tfrac{1}{4}-x+x^2-\tfrac{1}{2}+x-1 \\
                  &= x^2-\tfrac{5}{4}
     \end{aligned}
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of the space saved with nested `aligned`. Thank you very much for the `\tfrac` suggestion, I like it. You aren't wrong about aligning everything about aligning everything at the `=`, but I did want to find out how to do this.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a short explanation as to why the space is saved this way?

Comment: @Meragone - There are two sources of the space saving. The (hopefully obvious) one is because the fraction expressions produced by `\tfrac` are much smaller than those produced by `\frac` (which, for the case at hand, works out to be the same as `\dfrac`). Second, LaTeX by design inserts less whitespace above and below a `\[ \begin{aligned} ... \end{aligned} \]` object than it does above and below a `\begin{align*} ... \end{align}` object. As to *why* this is the case, I'm not sure. (I just somehow happened to know about this, so I decided to make use of it...)

Comment: Ah, thank you, that's all I was wondering. It might have to do with what I included in my comment on egreg's answer.

Comment: @Meragone - Not sure whether or not the fact that the *widths* of `aligned` and `gathered` environments are "minimal" (in the LaTeX sense of the term) has implications for the heights of these environments and, in particular, whether their heights are minimal as well. I honestly don't know.

Answer (score 5):

You'd need `&` in front of the `split`, but, alas, it can't work.

But you can use `aligned` instead.

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  &f(x)=x^2-x-1\\
  &g(x)=\frac{1}{2}-x\\
  &\begin{aligned}
   (f\circ g)(x)
      &=f(g(x))=f\Bigl(\frac{1}{2}-x\Bigr)
       =\Bigl(\frac{1}{2}-x\Bigr)^2-\Bigl(\frac{1}{2}-x\Bigr)-1\\
      &= \frac{1}{4}-x+x^2-\frac{1}{2}+x-1
   \end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this works flawlessly. I seem to have found an explanation: "But variants `gathered`, `aligned`, and `alignedat` are provided whose
total width is the actual width of the contents; thus they can be used as a
component in a containing expression."

Comment: @Meragone This text seems to be copied from this document: http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsldoc.tex. Citing is not important in comments (at least for me, but I always cite), and +1 researching/reading the docs.

Answer (score 3):

As you have no alignment at the outer level, I think `gather` is more appropriate than `align`, I'm specifying flush left equations with the `fleqn` option. Then as others have noted, `aligned` can produce the nested alignment.

I think here I prefer the second version that uses `\tfrac` rather than `\frac` to get a more compact layout.

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  f(x)=x^2-x-1\\
  g(x)=\frac{1}{2}-x\\
  \begin{aligned}
    (f\circ g)&=f(g(x))=f(\frac{1}{2}-x)=(\frac{1}{2}-x)^2-(\frac{1}{2}-x)-1\\
    &= \frac{1}{4}-x+x^2-\frac{1}{2}+x-1
  \end{aligned}
\end{gather*}

or
\begin{gather*}
  f(x)=x^2-x-1\\
  g(x)=\tfrac{1}{2}-x\\
  \begin{aligned}
    (f\circ g)&=f(g(x))=f(\tfrac{1}{2}-x)=(\tfrac{1}{2}-x)^2-(\tfrac{1}{2}-x)-1\\
    &= \tfrac{1}{4}-x+x^2-\tfrac{1}{2}+x-1
  \end{aligned}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You didn't point out that the `[fleqn]` is what justifies the equations. I do like that suggestion, but I wish that it was clearly stated as an element. I also appreciate the `\tfrac`, I am going to use it in these sort of cases.

Comment: @Meragone chosing left aligned or centred formulae is usually a document choice so `fleqn`seems more natural than using an alignment. Especially `align` with leading `&` which is not designed to give flush left equations it just does it by omitting the left hand side so the "right hand side" which is normally flush to the = appears flush to the left margin.

Comment: @Meragone I added mention of `fleqn` to the answer.